# Posting x-form-www-urlencoded string from an HTML Form

Tags: javascript, html

I'm utilising a third-party hosted web control that needs to be initiated via a form post which targets an iframe.

I need to populate certain data items on the form inputs (I'm calling my own API to get these data), then submit the form.

```
<iframe id="iframe" name="iframe" height="650px" width="100%" frameBorder="0"></iframe>
<form action="https://yodlee.com/authenticate/" method="POST" target=”iframe”>
    <input type="text" name="app" value="10003600" />
    <input type="text" name="rsession" />
    <input type="text" name="token" />
    <input type="text" name="ex" />
    <input type="text" name="redirectReq" value="true"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('form').submit(); 
</script>
```

Since the form targets the iframe, when it gets posted, the the hosted web app is initiated from the iFrame.

My Question is:
Rather than populating this form and its input elements individually, can I just return a single x-form-www-urlencoded string from my Web service, and somehow post that either using the form (or by Javascript) while **crucially** targeting the iFrame?

Comment: uh, I guess you could POST using javascript and then do something with the response, like placing it into the iframe.... but your "architecture" seems seriously messed up...

Comment: Thanks for your assessment of "my architecture" I'm dealing with a third-party service, I don't have a lot of control of this